# Trying to sort my multi-dimensional array by price

Tags: php

I am very new to PhP and programming in general, I looked at similar questions and tried most of the offered solutions but couldn't find a way to apply it to my situation.

I made a filter option on a page, I am now trying to have the filtered results come out as Ascending by price. If I am to use a sort function, where should I be using it in the code for it to make sense?

```
<?php
require "voitures.php";  [my array][1]

if (isset($_GET["prixMin"])) {
  $prixMin = $_GET["prixMin"];
  $prixMax =  $_GET["prixMax"];
  $voitures2 = [];
  foreach ($voitures as $voiture) {
    if ($prixMin <= $voiture['prix'] && $prixMax >= $voiture['prix']) {
      $voitures2[] = $voiture;
    }
  }
}
?>
      <form action=" <?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="GET">
      <label for="prixMin">Prix minimal : </label>
      <input type="text" name="prixMin" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['prixMin'])){ echo $_GET['prixMin']; }?>">
      <label for="prixMax">Prix maximal : </label>
      <input type="text" name="prixMax" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['prixMax'])){ echo $_GET['prixMax']; }?>">

      <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="g" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content)">
      <div class="t">Marques</div>
      <div class="t">Modeles</div>
      <div class="t">Annee</div>
      <div class="t">Prix</div>
      
      <?php if (isset($_GET['prixMin'])) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($voitures2 as $voiture2) : ?>
          <div class="l">
            <div class="c dr"><?= $voiture2["marque"] ?></div>
            <div class="c"><?= $voiture2["modele"] ?></div>
            <div class="c"><?= $voiture2["annee"] ?></div>
            <div class="c mi"><?= $voiture2["prix"] ?></div>
          </div>

        <?php endforeach ?>

      <?php } else { ?>
        <?php foreach ($voitures as $voiture) : ?>
          <div class="l">
            <div class="c dr"><?= $voiture["marque"] ?></div>
            <div class="c"><?= $voiture["modele"] ?></div>
            <div class="c"><?= $voiture["annee"] ?></div>
            <div class="c mi"><?= $voiture["prix"] ?></div>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_sort_by_column($voitures2,'prix',SORT_DESC)

function array_sort_by_column($array, $column, $direction = SORT_ASC) {
    $reference_array = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $row) {
        $reference_array[$key] = $row[$column];
    }
    array_multisort($reference_array, $direction, $array);
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Please remember to include a small explanation on how your code works and why you think it will solve the question being asked. Code-only answers are prone to being downvoted and/or deleted.